# Merge [iq] and [quadrature] tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I suggest merging the [iq] and [quadrature] tags (or making them synonymous), and keep [quadrature] as the tag name. I tried to do this myself, but everything under "Tags" seems to be read-only.

Comment: [btw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UP3IU.png)

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Right -- I've been too busy to bring my site back up. Soon, I hope :-)

Answer (score 4):

I agree. I've merged them, and it re-tagged 9 questions from <kbd>iq</kbd> to <kbd>quadrature</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks! I hope the process was automatic and you didn't have to re-tag by hand.

Comment: @MBaz No, completely automatic. The Mod tools here are pretty awesome. :-)